# Why is this discriminated union not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**What I want to happen**

Based on the `href` props truthiness ts should infer that the rest of the props are appropriate for the `Link` or `Button`

Instead I receive the following error telling me that the types conflict on the button element.

```ts
Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; disabled?: boolean | undefined; form?: string | undefined; formAction?: string | ((formData: FormData) => void) | undefined; ... 271 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; href: Url; as?: Url | undefined; replace?: boolean | undefined; scroll?: boolean | undefined; shallow?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; href: Url; as?: Url | undefined; replace?: boolean | undefined; scroll?: boolean | undefined; shallow?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
          Type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
            Type 'HTMLAnchorElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 13 more.
```

Here is the component in question

```ts
import React, { ButtonHTMLAttributes, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { cva, VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority";
import Link, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from "next/link";

const buttonOrLinkStyles = cva(
  "text-center font-medium rounded-2xl w-full text-white p-3 transition-colors duration-150",
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        primary: "bg-blue-500 hover:bg-cyan-400",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: "primary",
    },
  }
);

type LinkProps =PropsWithChildren< VariantProps<typeof buttonOrLinkStyles> & NextLinkProps>;

type ButtonProps = PropsWithChildren<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
  VariantProps<typeof buttonOrLinkStyles>>;


type ButtonOrLinkProps = ButtonProps |  LinkProps;

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonOrLinkProps> = ({
  variant,
  children,
  ...rest
}: ButtonOrLinkProps) => {
  const isLink = (props: ButtonOrLinkProps): props is LinkProps => {
    return "href" in props;
  };

  const className = buttonOrLinkStyles({ variant });
  const isLinkElement = isLink(rest);

  if (isLinkElement) {
    return (
      <Link {...rest} className={className}>
        {children}
      </Link>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <button {...rest} className={className}>
        {children}
      </button>
    );
  }
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your type guard. Because you call `isLink` with `rest` instead of `props`, `isLink` really tests whether the argument is `LinkProps` without `variant` and `children`, not `LinkProps` in its entirety. If you correct the type guard, then the code works:

```
  const isLink = (props: ButtonOrLinkProps): props is Omit<LinkProps, 'variant' | 'children'> => {
    return 'href' in props;
  };
```

Or perhaps more accurately (but also more verbosely):

```
  const isLink = (rest: Omit<ButtonOrLinkProps, 'variant' | 'children'>): rest is Omit<LinkProps, 'variant' | 'children'> => {
    return 'href' in rest;
  };
```

But the simplest fix is to dispense with the `isLink` function altogether:

```
  if ('href' in rest) {
    return (
      <Link {...rest} className={className}>
        {children}
      </Link>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <button {...rest} className={className}>
        {children}
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Whilst this makes more sense and I'll adjust my code to account for the missing `children`, this unfortunately didn't do it. It can tell fine that I'm using `LinkProps` in the first branch of the if statement however it can't deduce that the second branch would be `ButtonProps`

Comment: @SaintPreston: I forgot to account for `variant`. I've updated my answer.